# Getting the time difference format on the created column in a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

When extracting items in a custom list is it possible to extract the created column as the time difference format from the time uploaded  such as this format '18 hours ago' etc., and if not therefore i should get the SharePoint server time and manually code the time difference between the current time server time and the created time , then so how could i able to get SharePoint server time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening just because of SharePoint Time Zone. If you need to show the `DateTime` as your local `DateTime`, you can use `Date.parseLocale`. See in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb397521(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
var a = Date.parseLocale(value, formats);
```

Also you can check http://momentjs.com/

Comment: cheers for the info.

Comment: which one you are going to use `moment.js` or `Date.parseLocale`

Comment: I think moment.js will satisfy !